# WTForms - set flag through validator

Tags: python, validation, wtforms

I want to implement an *email or username* field with Flask and WTForms. My class looks something like this:

```python
class LoginForm(Form):
    email_or_username = StringField('Email or username', validators=[Required()])
    ...
```

What I want is to use the `Email()` validator, not to raise a `ValidationError`, but to set a flag, so that then I can, in my view:

```python
if form.email_or_username.flags.email:
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email_or_username.data).first()
else:
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.email_or_username.data).first()
...
```

I've checked the docs but I still get no clue. Any idea of how I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: I read the documentation and it looks like what you want is a custom validator.

Comment: Yes, I need a custom validator. Just that I don't know how to construct it. I tried to use the `Email()` validator inside, but I have no clue as if I even can, so I just reused its regular expression. But then I'm not sure how to set the flag, the examples in the docs seem to refer to these as flags about the _field_ itself, not about its _content_.

Comment: You could create a subclass of the `Email` validator and override the `__call__` method to set your flag instead of raising `ValidationError`. Put a call to the superclass `__call__` method inside a `try...except ValidationError` block. Set the flag in the exception handler.